# How to get RTSP URL from Public Earthcam videos

Tags: rtsp

I am new to video analytics and in my company, I was asked to explore the options to scan and analyze objects/persons, etc. I was able to complete the code and tested that with a sample video file. Now I wanted to check the same with live public videos. I found earthcam videos showing traffic and people from Times Square and other places. I am not able to find the RTSP URL from those videos.

I could find youtube live videos like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AdUw5RdyZxI

I don't know how to convert this into an RTSP URL. Is there any way to do that?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Many webcam video links will have been converted into a format which is easier to stream and transport over the internet, so won't be using RTSP by the time you look at it.

From a quick look at EarthCam for example, the videos are using ABR streaming protocols (see here for more on ABR: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42365034/334402).

For example, using Safari on a MAC, you can see the m3u8 index file and TS video segment files in the network inspector:

[image]

If you are simply looking for an RTSP stream to test against, you may find it easier to actually generate your own if you have a webcam with an RTSP output. You can also build a stream using a computer or a raspberry PI - see here for some more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66530587/334402

There do not seem to be many reliable public test streams for RTSP - the one below is the most reliable I have found and is working now at the time of writing:

- https://www.wowza.com/html/mobile.html

(Go to the page at the above link and copy the RTSP link there and confirm in VLC player first)